# Sum of the arithmetic series

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic

If the sum of a Arithmetic series when i = 1 equate the equation below:

[image]

What is the general forumla for when i starts at a value other than 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $$\sum_{i=k}^na_i=\sum_{i=1}^na_i-\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}a_i$$